Given a profit margin, how to determine the selling price?
I am selling a product and want a $20\%$ margin on the selling price.
To determine the selling price, my plan was to multiply the cost price by $(1+0.2),$ but the salesperson that I'm working with tells me that I should divide the cost price by $(1-0.2)$ instead.
Which formula is right, and why?

It depends entirely on what you want "a 20% profit margin" to mean. It could mean you add 20% to your buy-in / production price to set the selling price, so if your "purchase price / production cost" is £100, you'd sell it at £120 for a 20% markup. But it could mean  that 20% of your sale price is "profit", in which case you'd sell it for £125. Both those "definitions" of "profit margin" are in use, and it's pointless to argue that either is "better" than the other (except that you as a retailer make more profit with the second definition, obviously! :)

@FumbleFingers: "it's pointless to argue...". Well, the one that your company accountant tells you your company uses in its own accounts, is "better". It's pointless arguing which one that is if, as you suggest, both are in use by professionally-qualified accountants ;-) AFAIK "gross margin" is universally acclaimed to be "100% - (cost/revenue)", which means £125 is correct, but I might be wrong. And "gross margin" is not the only "profit margin".

Fundamentally, if this is a question from "algebra pre-calculus" then it should define its terms, not include a sub-question from an accountancy course. If all else fails, explain under what conditions each would be correct, and if you lose marks for not knowing the definition of "profit margin", then hey ho. But since the exercise says a 20% margin "on the selling price", and only the questioner ever mentioned "profit margin" in their paraphrased title, I'd wager that 20% of price is the expected definition.

@FumbleFingers Both those "definitions" of "profit margin" are in use $\quad$ I just googled, and could find only sources compatible with the second definition. Could you site an example where the term "profit margin" is being used to mean markup percentage?

@ryang: You surprise me. For example, A craftsman makes a chair for $80 and sells it to make a 20% profit on its cost price. It says there Selling Price = Cost Price + Profit = $80 + $16 = $96. But by my second definition above, obviously he's only made 16.6% profit. Drawing a distinction between "profit margin" and "markup percentage" is just nitpicking.

@FumbleFingers Further to my previous comment, it turns out that previous Mathematics.StackExchange posts also don't define "profit margin" as equivalent to, or use it to mean, markup percentage. Overall, it appears that profit margin and markup percentage are conventionally (and uncontroversially) distinct concepts—notwithstanding that the OP, you and (incidentally) I had previously assumed that the former was merely jargon for the latter.

@ryang: I never assumed the two terms meant the same thing to people who might have reason to care about the real-world difference. I just meant that difference makes no difference to me, so I wouldn't bother to make it. To me, it's akin to distinguishing between a sociopath and a psychopath. There is in principle a difference, but most people don't know or care about that, and will treat the two terms as interchangeable. The OP here is free to chose how to calculate his profit, and to non-specialists, he's free to refer to it however he wants.

@FumbleFingers All I'm pointing out is that I'm unable to unearth (nor have you cited) any empirical evidence to support your claim that non-specialists, like general affairs reporters, sometimes use "profit margin" to mean markup percentage.


I want a $20\%$ margin on the selling price.

In your computation $$\text{selling price}=1.2\times\text{cost price},$$ the markup percentage (profit $\div$ cost price), or percentage profit, will be $\dfrac{20}{100}=20\%.$
In your coworker's computation \begin{align}\text{selling price}&=\text{cost price}\div(1-0.2)\\&=1.25\times\text{cost price},\end{align} the profit margin (profit $\div$ selling price) will be $\dfrac{25}{125}=20\%,$ as desired.
P.S. While profit margin is the more immediately relevant metric to sellers, markup percentage is the more fundamental concept, at least to analysts and buyers.

Let $S$ be the selling price and $C$ be the cost price . For a 20%  margin , we want the profit ($S-C$) to be 20% So:
$$S-C=0.2S\iff C=S(1-0.2)\iff S=\frac{C}{1-0.2}$$
Your formula is used to mark up the cost by a flat percentage , whereas the salesperson’s formula is used to calculate the selling price so that the profit margin is a specific percentage of the selling price.
